# Linq: select from multiple class members in List

Tags: c#, string, list, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;


public class Data
{
    public List<string> ListData { get; } = new List<string>() { "listData1", "listData2" };
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
    

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var list = new List<Data>() { new Data() { Name = "Data1" }, new Data() { Name = "Data2" } };
        System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list.Select(x => new {x.Name, x.ListData})));
    }
}
```

Current Output:

> { Name = Data1, ListData =
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] }, { Name = Data2, ListData = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] }

I was not able to select the ListData list in my anonymous type `list.Select(x => new {x.Name, x.ListData})`

How can I extract the elements of the ListData list from the Data class in the Select statement? I want an output like Data1: listData1, listData2, Data2: listData1, listData2.

Comment: `SelectMany` method?

Comment: Yes. With an example would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select as interpolated string from your `Data` array and then use `Join` for `ListData` too:

```
var list = new List<Data>() { new Data() { Name = "Data1" }, new Data() { Name = "Data2" } };
System.Console.WriteLine(
                string.Join(", ", 
                    list.Select(x => 
                        $"{x.Name}:{string.Join(",",x.ListData)}")
                    )
                );
```

see also [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote, but I've reached my daily vote limit   :-(

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two steps:

1. output of `Data` list separated with comma
2. output of one `Data`: its `Name` and `ListData` strings separated with comma

This means you have to use two nested `String.Join` calls, one for each step:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list.Select(x => String.Concat(x.Name, ": ", String.Join(", ", x.ListData)))));
```

This gives you the exact expected output.